# How do I create a UI like the insert snippet one in a Visual Studio editor window

Tags: visual-studio, languageservice

From inside the text editor window, I can right click and select "Insert Snippet..." and I am presented with a search box that I can type and find a snippet.  Once selected, the editor window is updated with text from the snippet.  How does this work?  Can this be done from MEF or do I have to use the MPF and implement a language service?  If someone could just point me in a direction, looking at the MSDN docs is a little overwhelming, it seems there are number of ways to handle any task (MEF, MPF, Implementing interfaces directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, after digging through reflector code, this is an internal feature.  You can add to the snippets, there is a whole process for installing your own snippets and registering a key word to invoke them but this has to be done statically.  I see no way to alter the snippet list and provide your own snippet text at run time, which was my originally goal.